# Exclude some elements from Canvas TranslateTransform

Tags: silverlight, canvas

I'm creating a design environment in Silverlight 5, user can drag/drop some items from panels located ad left side of the screen. Also user can zoom/pan scene via mouse and scrollbars. Canvas has a TranslateTransform which is manipulated while panning the scene, but I don't want my UI elements to be panned. How can I exclude these elements from being affected by panning process?

I use following Canvas Transforms in XAML:

```
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup x:Name="transformGroup">
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="CanvasScale" ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0"></ScaleTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="CanvasPan" ></TranslateTransform>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
```

then I change CanvasScale and CanvasPan in code to zoom/pan scene, but all objects (including UI elements) are affected, my scene is a little complicated so I think the best (or the only) way is to exclude UI elements from these transforms.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project, but having difficulty visualizing what you mean? Are you saying you just want (as example) some buttons and random UI stuff to stay put while your canvas stuff under them do their thing separately?

Comment: Yes, you can imagine my application something like MS-Paint, I have some standard UI (status bar, toolbars and...) and a scene in which user can draw. UI objects should stay unmoved when user pans the scene, how is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok, now that I think I know what you mean, what you want to do is pretty painless and can be accomplished just using organization of your objects in the `DOM` to reflect the structure you want. So in your case it would be something like this (in pseudo as an example)

```
<Grid>
              <!-- Your Canvas -->
   <Canvas>
      <Canvas.RenderTransform>
         <TransformGroup x:Name="transformGroup">
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="CanvasScale" ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0"/>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="CanvasPan"/>
         </TransformGroup>
      </Canvas.RenderTransform>
   </Canvas>

             <!-- Your UI elements -->
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Button/>
      <TextBlox/>
      <CheckBox/>
   </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Then this way you're basically just floating those UI elements over the other stuff in the `DOM` tree allowing you the effect you're going for.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll give it a go, and let you know about the result.

Comment: No worries brother, let me know if not and we'll get ya sorted either way. Have a good weekend!

Comment: I've tested this what you said, but it seems not working. UI arrangement is messed up hugely. I think I should work on only one Canvas. Is there a way to exclude some elements from Canvas TranslateTransform? Or is it possible to neutralize the transform on some elements?

Comment: I would have to see what you're doing to give a more accurate idea, but you're going to have to break that inherited relationship between transforms and your UI stuff, generally you just use the DOM to do that like I showed. It sounds like how you have things organized might not be the best route so far and could use some refactoring.

Comment: @Ali_dotNet updated my answer, sorry didnt see your response sooner. Same concept still applies, you'll just need to detach the association between your `Canvas` and your other stuff.